# Sitecore Rocks, getting data of multiselect field?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-rocks

I have the following Sitecore Rocks query.   @#Tags# refers to Treelist field that contains 1 or more items.   With the query, I get back a pipe delimited list of the *Tags* item IDs.   How can I get the *Tags* item name instead of the ID?

```
select @#Tags#, @@Path from /sitecore/content/Sites/MySite/Assets/Pages//*[@@templatename="Dynamic Content"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you cannot get the tag item name instead of the ID in one query.

Sitecore query has it's limitation - it only return items or their field (attributes).

Your query returns items which use `Dynamic Content` template and **their** properties: `Tags` and `Path`. `Name` in that case would be the an attribute of the items which are chosen in the `Tags` field. From what I know you cannot get attributes from both `Dynamic Content` items and their Tags in a single query.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Oh well, it was worth a shot.